# Batch script that will take directory name from *txt file list and change atributes of all directories

Tags: batch-file

I am looking for a batch script that will take names of directories from list in *txt file and then change atribute of each directory that name is on the list.

For example I have this list in log.txt file:

```
Folder1
Folder2
Folder3
Folder4
....
```

And I want to hide all those directories. 
Any sugestions?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: If your text file content is just a list of directory names, as in your example, how does the batch file know their location? or in fact whether they even exist? in order to modify their attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`for /f`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loop and [`attrib`](https://ss64.com/nt/attrib.html).

I've set `delims` to `?` as that's unallowed in file names.

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=? eol=?" %%D in ("log.txt") do if exist "%%~D" attrib "%%~D" +H
```

Comment: I would advise in future that you do not answer a question, which you knew to be off topic, _(as can be seen by your vote to close)_! Answering off topic questions inevitably only encourages further off topic questions to be posted.